# How to grant permission to self-defined functions?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, permissions, google-sheets-custom-function

I have in Google Sheets a table with the name of a contact in column 1 and want to retrieve their email address in column two.

This is the code I have used:

```
function email(name) {
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContactsByName(name);
  var emailAdd = contacts[0].getPrimaryEmail();
  return emailAdd;
}
```

I now try to test this function in a Sheet, by writing `=email(A1)` (for example) in column 2, and get the following error message:

> You do not have permission to call getContactsByName.

How can I overcome this problem? I have tried to go into Resources>Advanced Google services and enabling the contacts API, without more luck.

Comment: @Rubén Is there a reason you removed the worksheet-function tag? I think that's apropos here.  You can always ping an editor and ask them about their change rather than just reversing it.

Comment: @jonsca: The reason to remove the worksheet-function tag is that it's not related to the question. The excerpt for this tag says: "This tag is for spreadsheet questions where the question or answers involve an in-the-cell worksheet function, as opposed to some form of code." A custom function, like the one posted by the OP is not "opposed to some form of code", it actually uses Google Apps Script code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Custom functions can't call services that require authorization. Source: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions.

The way to overcome the problem is to use another way for calling the function, like assign the script to a custom menu, an image, an installable trigger or by running it from the Script Editor.